# Recortar imagem com JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tem como usar o `JCrop` ou alguma outra biblioteca pra recortar imagem, mas eu que defina um tamanho padrão? Que possa apenas mexer o quadrado sobre a imagem? Tentei usar o `JCrop` mas o usuário é quem define o tamanho que quer cortar a imagem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ao ler a documentação encontrei a função `setSelect`, que se demonstrou a solução para esse problema. Segue o código:

```
$(function() {
  $('#jcrop_target').Jcrop({
    minSize: [200, 200],
    allowSelect: false,
    allowResize: false
  }, function() {
    this.setSelect([0, 0, 200, 200]);
  });
});
```

Para alterar o tamanho padrão da caixa mude o tamanho definido em `minSize: [200, 200]`.
Demonstração no [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/fahoxeli).

Comment: +1, mas onde você encontrou isso na documentação?

Comment: http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Manual.html#Setting_Options

Comment: Vi a função `setSelect` nessa página. Mas em nenhum lugar do site há qualquer ocorrência das propriedades `allowSelect` e `allowResize`, as quais acho serem parte importante da solução.

Comment: @Renan No começo eu estava usando as propriedades `maxSize` e `minSize` para evitar o resize perambulando pelas demonstrações, achei essa: http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=advanced onde são citados todas essas propriedades.

Comment: Conheço essa página. Reitero o que eu disse em minha resposta: não está na documentação oficial, você tem que ver o código fonte para ver que essas propriedades existem.

Answer (score 4):

É uma coisa que é muito mal documentada mesmo - procurei documentação oficial [no site do Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_API.html) mas não encontrei absolutamente nada.

No entanto, é possivel. Vamos supor que o objeto que você está utilizando tenha id `foo`, então faça o seguinte:

```
var api = $("#foo").Jcrop({allowResize: false});
```

Ou, de forma mais elegante:

```
var options = {
    allowResize: false
}
var api = $("#foo").Jcrop(options);
```

Note que você ainda tem que indicar o tamanho da área de seleção por conta própria.

Existem mais opções além da `allowResize`, mas infelizmente é mais fácil descobrí-las mergulhando no código do Jcrop do que esperando que os programadores da Tapmodo se motivem a documentar o próprio trabalho direito.